# This application failed to start because it could not find or load the Qt platform plugin “cocoa”

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyqt5

I followed the following instruction to install PyQt5 for python2.7.

My system is Mac OS Al Captain. Qt5.5 library, PyQt5_gpl-5.7, sip-4.18.1 libraries are used.

```
  mkdir pyqt
  cd pyqt/
  virtualenv qtenv
  source qtenv/bin/activate

  mkdir tmp
  cp /Users/ge/Downloads/PyQt-gpl-5.4.1.tar.gz ./tmp
  cp /Users/ge/Downloads/sip-4.16.7.tar.gz ./tmp
  cd tmp/
  tar xvf sip-4.16.7.tar.gz 
  tar xvf PyQt-gpl-5.4.1.tar.gz 

  cd sip-4.16.7
  python configure.py -d /Users/ge/pyqt/qtenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages --arch x86_64
  make
  sudo make install
  sudo make clean

  cd ../PyQt-gpl-5.4.1
  python configure.py --destdir /Users/ge/pyqt/qtenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages --qmake /Applications/Qt/5.4/clang_64/bin/qmake 
  make
  sudo make install
  sudo make clean
```

However, It generates error as below and refuses to start the application codes as below:

```
from PyQt5 import QtGui  # (the example applies equally well to PySide)
import pyqtgraph as pg

## Always start by initializing Qt (only once per application)
app = QtGui.QApplication([])

## Define a top-level widget to hold everything
w = QtGui.QWidget()

## Create some widgets to be placed inside
btn = QtGui.QPushButton('press me')
text = QtGui.QLineEdit('enter text')
listw = QtGui.QListWidget()
plot = pg.PlotWidget()

## Create a grid layout to manage the widgets size and position
layout = QtGui.QGridLayout()
w.setLayout(layout)

## Add widgets to the layout in their proper positions
layout.addWidget(btn, 0, 0)   # button goes in upper-left
layout.addWidget(text, 1, 0)   # text edit goes in middle-left
layout.addWidget(listw, 2, 0)  # list widget goes in bottom-left
layout.addWidget(plot, 0, 1, 3, 1)  # plot goes on right side, spanning 3 rows

## Display the widget as a new window
w.show()

## Start the Qt event loop
app.exec_()
```

The errors generated are:

```
This application failed to start because it could not find or load the Qt platform plugin “cocoa”
```

Then I searched with google, a temporary solution is to add an env path to the system called:

```
QT_QPA_PLATFORM_PLUGIN_PATH = {QT_SRC}/plugins
```

I would like to know if there is any way to set it up when I install pyqt5 instead of setting this path to my system after installation. It should be some configure.py options, right?

Comment: Checkout what `macdeployqt` tool does.

Comment: @hyde Which part should I check? macdeployqt? which part?

Comment: That tool helps in deploying C++ Qt apps. It might help you figure out where to put the platform plugin, so that it is found. Maybe.